# if there is at least one Na in the line, make the line Na

Tags: r, dataframe

my data:

```
    structure(list(col1 = 1:6, col2 = c(NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
    col3 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), col4 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    NA, 2L), col5 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L), GROUP = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want to get a new date frame in which, if NA occurs, then replace the entire line with NA from the combination `list(c(1,2),c(3,4,5))`.

What I want to get:

```
data= structure(list(col1 = c(NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), col2 = c(NA, 
NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), col3 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), col4 = c(2L, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L), col5 = c(3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L), GROUP = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

UPDATE:
I tried to do so:

```
list_v <- list(c(1,2),c(3,4,5))
data1 <- do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(list_v, function(i)data[complete.cases(data[c(i)]),i]))
```

I need not to delete the line with Where there is at least one NA, but to replace the remaining elements with Na where there is at least one Na

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```r
l <- lapply(list(c(1,2), c(3,4,5)), \(i) df[, i])

cbind.data.frame(lapply(l, \(y) t(apply(y, 1, \(x) {
  if(any(is.na(x))) x[1:length(x)] <- NA
  x
}))))

#  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1   NA   NA    1    2    3
#2   NA   NA    1    2    3
#3    3    3   NA   NA   NA
#4    4    4   NA   NA   NA
#5    5    5   NA   NA   NA
#6    6    6    1    2    3
```

---

Using `apply` and an `if else` statement, you can do:

```r
t(apply(df, 1, function(x){
  if(any(is.na(x[1:2])))
    x[1:2] <- NA
  else if(any(is.na(x[3:5])))
    x[3:5] <- NA
  x
}))

#     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 GROUP
#[1,]   NA   NA    1    2    3     1
#[2,]   NA   NA    1    2    3     1
#[3,]    3    3   NA   NA   NA     1
#[4,]    4    4   NA   NA   NA     2
#[5,]    5    5   NA   NA   NA     2
#[6,]    6    6    1    2    3     2
```

Here, `apply` repeats a function (defined in the third parameter) on each rows (`MARGIN = 1`) of `df`.

Comment: This will change the class of the undelying data. Take for example, 1:2 were numeric and 3:5 were character, then your method will have unexpected results where all the values will be transformed to character.

Comment: This method doesn't really suit me, I wanted to select columns using a list of combinations

Comment: and what does the construction mean `\(i) df[, i]`

Comment: \ is a shortcut for `function` since R 4.1. `\(i) df[, i]` basically cuts the data into groups based on the list